# Weird issue with OpenCV drawContours on android

Tags: android, opencv, draw

I stumbled upon a weird problem with OpenCV drawContours on android.
Sometimes, (without apparent pattern) function drawContours produces this:

[drawContours http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/9031/screenshotgps.png](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/9031/screenshotgps.png)

while it should obviously produce just the white part.

To put it in context:
I detect edges using canny algorithm and then I find contours with

```
Imgproc.findContours(dil, contours, dummy, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Then i select several contours that fit some requirements and I add them to a list:

```
List<MatOfPoint> goodContours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
```

After that I randomly select one contour and I draw it (filled with white) on mat and convert it to android Bitmap:

```
Mat oneContour = new Mat(orig.rows(), orig.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
int index = (int) (Math.random() * goodContours.size());
Imgproc.drawContours(oneContour, goodContours, index, new Scalar(255, 255, 255), -1);
Bitmap oneContourBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(oneContour.cols(), oneContour.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(oneContour, oneContourBitmap);
```

Most of the times I get what I expect: white patch on a pure black background, but sometimes I get the above. I'm totally at a loss here. I suspect there could be some memory leakage but I try hard to release all Mat's immediately after they are of no use anymore (I also tried to release them at the end of a function where it all happens but without effect) but I'm unable to pinpoint the source of the problem.

Has anyone had similar issues?

I first discovered this on OpenCV 2.4.0 but it stays the same on 2.4.3.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Do your requirements to filter the contours have a minimum area test? If you filter contours by area, that should get rid of those small lines which look a lot like a normal output from canny. If you are indeed filtering by area, I think something is wrong in your filtering logic.

Comment: Yes, I first use convexHull on a contour and then I calculate area to select only those that are less than defined MAX_AREA (which is significantly less then picture area).

Comment: But you should also select those with area larger than some MIN_AREA, to filter small contours.